# How do I collapse code for a case in a switch?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, netbeans-8

Inside a JavaScript `switch` instruction, different `case`(s) may contain much code. Therefore it could be useful to collapse (fold) the code for cases other than the one I am working on.

I use Netbeans. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Previously unknown to me, but very handy!

Put braces around the code that is inside the case: Netbeans will display the fold/unfold symbol then you can proceed as usual.

```
switch (kNumCell)
{
    case "0":
    {
      // code comes here
    }
    break;
     // …
}
```

Comment: Just to add that you can also configure how you want code folding to work for JavaScript in general: **Tools > Options > Editor > Folding > Language >** then select **JavaScript** from the drop list.

Comment: Hum… Actually you can specify to collapse code blocks, but as far as I have tried this rule does not apply to switch cases. Did you try it for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is adding curly braces around your case statement:

```
switch (num){
    case 1: {
        //Do something
        break;
    }
    default: {
        //Do something
        break;
    }
}
```

The more complex solution is to reconfigure code folding to for JavaScript in general: Tools > Options > Editor > Folding > Language >, then select JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a custom **Surround with Code folding** suggestion on code selection, so you can fold any part of code you want. [Here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/SurroundWithCodeFolding) is a tutorial.

Comment: A very heavy solution to implement and cumbersome to use.